Prompt Builder Flex Template V/S Flow Agent action
I’m new to Agentforce. On the Account object, I have two fields: Customer Skill (e.g., "Cloud Computing," "Data Analytics") and Partner Skill (e.g., "AWS Certified," "Cybersecurity"). This is unstructured data, I need to extract these keywords and create child records for each skill combination.
I’ve identified two potential approaches:

Create a Flow with Agent Actions and associate it with a Topic.
Use a Flex Template, call the Promote Template Flow, and then link it to a Topic.

Which approach is better for this scenario, and why?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
